# How to solve a (simple) equation with respect to a function using Sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, solver

First of all sorry for the relatively simple/stupid question, but I really have tried everything and haven't came up with a solution.

I get an equation where symbols (r,theta,M,a) are there, but also a function of r: u_f(r).

`uf =sp.Function('u_φ')(r)`

If I substitute all the symbols with numerical values, i'll get an expression  with u_f(r_0), like this:

`MomentumR.subs({theta:sp.pi/2,M:1,a:0.9,r:2})`

`−0.0115244788566508*uφ^2(2)−0.175486420846152*uφ(2)+0.914728043583324`

Although it's a simple equation, how can I solve this with respect to  uφ(2) (the above expression is equal to zero in the Solver so thie variable MomentumR is just the above )

I have tried:

```
FF = `MomentumR.subs({theta:sp.pi/2,M:1,a:0.9,r:2})`
sp.solve(FF,uf)
sp.solve(FF,uf(2))
sp.solve(FF,uf(r))
```

and many more without results

EDIT: Just to present a simpler but of the same Logic example, If I could solve with respect to G(2), or If I could append a symbol to the function Call G(2), I would essentially solve the 1st problem too. Here is a simple code for it:

```
import sympy as sp
p = sp.Symbol('p')
M = sp.Symbol('M')
G = sp.Function('G')(p)

Eq = M*3*G**2+M**2*p*G+p
EqS = Eq.subs({M:1,p:2})
EqS
```

Comment: Can you show all the code needed to reproduce this?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I added a similar problem, cuz the one i have here uses some weird libraries (gravipy etc). This code results in the same problematic solving need tho :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 'gotcha' related to functions. If you want to be able to give the function a specific argument whenever you want then you need to define the name as a Python function or lambda or as a SymPy Function (not expression) or Lambda.

This creates something that can't be called; it's like `f(r)` and you can't do `f(r)(r)` because `f(r)` is an expression and you can't call an expression:

```
>>> uf =sp.Function('u_φ')(r)
```

It's simplest to just leave the `(r)` off in this case. Then,

```
>>> uf =sp.Function('u_φ')
>>> solve(uf(1) - 2)
[{u_φ(1): 2}]
>>> solve(uf(x)-2, uf(x))
[2]

>>>
```

Comment: Forgot to thank you btw, Really really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad it helped.